# How to specify multiple files as xmlSource in xslt task?

Tags: visual-studio-code, xslt, vscode-tasks, deltaxml

I am currently transforming xml to html with an xslt stylesheet. I use VS Code with the XSLT/XPath extension and have a tasks.json to do the transformation. It works fine for a single xml file, but I actually have multiple files, for which the same template applys and which should all be in the same html file.

My working tasks.json for a single file:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "xslt-js",
            "label": "Saxon-JS Transform (Briefe)",
            "xsltFile": "briefe/tei_to_html.xsl",
            "xmlSource": "briefe/3690096/3690096.xml",
            "resultPath": "edition.html",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$saxon-xslt-js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to use wildcards for the source `"briefe/**/*.xml"`, which results in an error: Failed to read XML source input (Failed to read ... /briefe/**/*.xml (no such file))
An array of the files (it's only a handful, so I could type them all in) is not possible, because xmlSource only accepts string.

I suppose I am able to handle multiple xml files in my stylesheet with for-each and document, but how do I specify multiple files as source in my task?

**Update:**

The goal is to process multiple xml files with one XSLT, to produce one result file.

I figured out, that I could feed a json as source:

```
...
"useJsonSource": true,
"xmlSource": "briefe/list.json",
...
```

I am trying to find out if I can process the json in xslt and this is the solution.

Comment: What do you want to achieve, run a single XSLT once, processing several input files together to produce one result file, or run the same XSLT against several input files, to produce several result files?

Comment: Your task could invoke a VS Code extension command to supply the required file-list. As the maintainer of the extension you're using, I will investigate adding this feature to the existing 'filePick' commands (that only select a single file) for XSLT documented at: https://deltaxml.github.io/vscode-xslt-xpath/run-xslt.html#references

Comment: @pgfearo the filePick is a quiet neat way, just tested it (with one file) out of curiosity :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this task with building a collection in a separate file `letters.xml` and used this as `xmlSource`.
The collection:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-model href="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>

<collection stable="true">
    <doc href="letter_1.xml"/>
    <doc href="letter_2.xml"/>
</collection>
```

With the last comment I switched from xslt-js to xslt, because using xslt-js was not a deliberate decision.

My tasks.json:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "xslt",
            "label": "xslt: Saxon Transform (Briefe Ebner-Eschenbach)",
            "saxonJar": "SaxonHE11-3J/saxon-he-11.3.jar",
            "xsltFile": "tei_to_html.xsl",
            "xmlSource": "letters.xml",
            "resultPath": "index.html",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$saxon-xslt"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In my `tei_to_html.xsl` I use the collection in a variable and create pages for the letters:

```
<xsl:variable name="letters" select="collection('briefe.xml')"/>

[...]

<xsl:for-each select="$letters">
            <xsl:result-document href="{concat('letter_', position(),'.html')}" method="html">
                <xsl:call-template name="letter_page"/>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

Thank you all for your help and input! I definitely learned a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `list.json` is e.g. an array of strings with file names `["file1.xml", "file2.xml", "file3.xml"]` your XSLT 3 would process e.g.

```
<xsl:template match=".[. instance of array(xs:string)]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="?*!doc(.)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Depending on the rest of your stylesheet you might want to output the HTML document structure around that `xsl:apply-templates` e.g.

```
<xsl:template match=".[. instance of array(xs:string)]">
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="?*!doc(.)"/>
    </body>
   </html>
</xsl:template>
```

While SaxonJS certainly has a `-json` option to process a JSON input file I haven't checked how/whether that interacts nicely with the `xslt-js` task in VS Code so be prepared to experiment how it works.

From the command line you would run e.g. `xslt3 -json:list.json -xsl:xslt.xsl` to have a `list.json` containing a JSON array with a string of file names processed by the stylesheet `xslt.xsl` where the template shown above would match that array and push each file named as a document node created with the `doc` function to any of your other templates.

Another option would be to pass the file names as a global parameter and to start with the named template `name="xsl:initial-template"`, option `-it` to do e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

<xsl:param name="file-names" as="xs:string*" select="'file1.xml', 'file2.xml', 'file3.xml'"/>

<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$file-names!doc(.)"/>
    </body>
   </html>
</xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: the xslt-js task has a 'useJsonSouce' that, when set 'true', handles the 'XmlSource' property as the JSON path/URI when invoking SaxonJS via the command-line - using -json: instead of -xsl:

Comment: @pgfearo, thanks, is there also an option to start with the named template `xsl:initial-template` instead of any XML or JSON source?

Comment: yes, it's the 'initialTemplate' property. The tasks JSON editor will complain if there's no 'XmlSouce' property but the task will still run

Comment: I'm investigating adding a multi-file-selection command that could supply the `file-names` values in the Visual Studio Code task. The existing commands are only for single-file selection and prompt the user to select a file: https://deltaxml.github.io/vscode-xslt-xpath/run-xslt.html#references

Comment: I tried out some other ways to make this work. For example I left my `xmlSource` the same and declared a variable in my stylesheet with a collection, containing the folder with all xml files:
`<xsl:variable name="letter" select="collection('letters')"/>` (this approach works in Oxygen XML Editor and I can iterate over all files with for-each and create multiple html files with result-document, but not with VS Code). I also tried to have a separate xml with the collection and use this as `xmlSource`.
Result: `Error FODC0002 at multi.xsl#7 Unknown collection (no collectionFinder supplied)`

Comment: @sleepyhead, I am afraid in terms of collections SaxonJS is not quite as easy to use as Saxon Java, I would suggest to start with reading the section on `collectionFinder` in https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation2/index.html#!api/transform, not sure how easy it is to integrate that with your code run by the VS code extension. Perhaps raise that problem with the collection as a different question.

Comment: @MartinHonnen your last comment was in fact the last piece of the puzzle. thank you so much!